# PETAPOCO No Property of type ICollection`1 found on object of type:

Tags: petapoco

I am having my sql as

```
Connection.db.FetchOneToMany<Project, CustomerProject>(x => x.ID, string.Format(@"
            SELECT * 
            FROM Project                   
            left join customerProject on customerProject.ProjectID = project.id
                where customerProject.CustomerID = @0  ORDER BY project.Name", customerID));
```

which is giving me the error

> No Property of type ICollection`1 found on object of type: Project

CustomerProject definition

> ID CustomerID ProjectID

Project definition

> ID Name

What is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a property of type `List<CustomerProject>` on your Project type. This is required if you want to do a `OneToMany<>` query. You will have to use the `[Ignore]` attribute on it too.